# How to extract an uppercase word from a string in Postgresql only if entire word is in capital letters

Tags: postgresql, substring, extract, uppercase

I am trying to extract words from a column in a table only if the entire word is in uppercase letters (I am trying to find all acronyms in a column). I tried using the following code, but it gives me all capital letters in a string even if it is just the first letter of a word.

```
SELECT title, REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[^A-Z]+', '', 'g') AS acronym
FROM table;
```

Here is my desired output:

| title | acronym |
| --- | --- |
| I will leave ASAP | ASAP |
| David James is LOL | LOL |
| BTW I went home | BTW |
| Please RSVP today | RSVP |

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
regexp_replace(title, '.*?\m([[:upper:]]+)\M.*', '\1 ', 'g')
```

- `.*?` matches arbitrary letters is a non-greedy fashion
- `\m` matches the beginning of a word
- `(` is the beginning of the part we are interested in
- `[[:upper:]]*` are arbitrarily many uppercase characters
- `)` is the end of that part we are interested in
- `\M` matches the end of a word
- `.*` matches arbitrary characters
- `\1` references the part delimited by the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You could try [REGEXP_MATCHES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function

```
WITH data AS 
          (SELECT 'I will leave ASAP' AS title  
UNION ALL SELECT 'David James is LOL' AS title
UNION ALL SELECT 'BTW I went home' AS title
UNION ALL SELECT 'Please RSVP today' AS title)
SELECT title, REGEXP_MATCHES(title, '[A-Z][A-Z]+', 'g') AS acronym
FROM data;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0BbNfJ0)